# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '013000ab7C8'

Tags: python, django, excel

I wanna parse excel& make dictionary and put the model(User) which has same user_id of dictionary. Now I got an error,`ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '013000ab7C8'` .
Of course,'013000ab7C8' is not int,but I really cannot understand why this error happens.
I wrote in views.py

```
#coding:utf-8
from django.shortcuts import render
import xlrd
from .models import User

book = xlrd.open_workbook('../data/excel1.xlsx')
sheet = book.sheet_by_index(1)

def build_employee(employee):
  if employee == 'leader':
     return 'l'
  if employee == 'manager':
     return 'm'
  if employee == 'others':
     return 'o'

for row_index in range(sheet.nrows):
  rows = sheet.row_values(row_index) 
  is_man = rows[4] != ""
  emp = build_employee(rows[5])
  user = User(user_id=rows[1], name_id=rows[2], name=rows[3], 
              age=rows[4],man=is_man,employee=emp)
  user.save()


files = glob.glob('./user/*.xlsx')

data_dict_key ={}
for x in files:
   if "$" not in x:
      book3 = xlrd.open_workbook(x)
      sheet3 = book3.sheet_by_index(0)
      cells = [
            ]
      data_dict = OrderedDict()
      for key, rowy, colx in cells:
          try:
              data_dict[key] = sheet3.cell_value(rowy, colx)
          except IndexError:
              data_dict[key] = None

       if data_dict['user_id'] in data_dict_key:

          data_dict_key[data_dict['user_id']].update(data_dict)
                       continue
       data_dict[data_dict_key['user_id']] = data_dict
       for row_number, row_data in data_dict_key.items():
           user1 = User.filter(user_id=row_data['user_id']).exists()
           if user1:
              user1.__dict__.update(**data_dict_key)
              user1.save()
```

I wanna connect excel files under user's folder & excel1.xlsx in 
user_id,it means if each data has same user_id,it will be connected.
data_dict_key is

```
dicts = {
    '013000ab7C8: OrderedDict([
        ('user_id', '013000ab7C8'),
        ('name_id', 'Blear'),
        ('nationality', 'America'),
        ('domitory', 'A'),
        ('group', 1),
    ]),
    '088009cd1W9': OrderedDict([
       ('user_id', '088009cd1W9'),
       ('name_id', 'Tom'),
       ('nationality': 'UK'),
       ('domitory': 'B'),
       ('group': 18),
    ])
}
```

What is wrong my code?How should I fix this?

Comment: can you provide the stack trace of the error to connect it to your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `user_id` field of your `User` model was specified as an `IntegerField` you obviously cannot do:

```
user = User(user_id=rows[1], name_id=rows[2], name=rows[3], ...)
#                   ^^^^^^^ Needs integer value
```

and also:

```
user1 = User.filter(user_id=row_data['user_id']).exists()
#                           ^^^^^^^^ Needs integer value
```

As an alternative, if the values are hex values, and contain no other alpha characters besides `a-f`, then you may want to assume the values are in base 16, and exploit that instead:

```
>>> int('013000ab7C8', 16)
81605081032
```

Not sure this is a stable solution though. 
You probably want to respecify those fields as direct integer values.

Comment: The other entry has `user_id: 088009cd1W9`, so it seems the letters are not hex values.

Answer (score 1):

Better if you show your models.py. You might have declared user_id as an integer field under the User class of your models.py. Hence you are getting this error.